# Is there a way to run scripts every time after a dependency is installed or updated?

Tags: npm

In PHP's package manager Composer you can define scripts that will be executed every time before or after you run certain CLI commands, like `composer update some-package`, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#command-events.

In NPM you can only define scripts which are run when your package is installed somewhere else (see https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#description), so for example `postinstall` will be executed when someone installs your package as a dependency. But I would like NPM to run a custom script from my package.json when I execute something like `npm update some-other-package`. Is their any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, hook scripts are the answer, https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#hook-scripts